# wp_nav_menu changed to wp_page_menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I've styled my navigation menu with the classes of wp_nav_menu .menu_item , .sub_menu etc.When i added a new page suddenly the whole menu was ruined the classes where changed to .page_item, .children the ul was wrapped with a div container.I checked the code and the function wwas wp_nav_menu...What should I do to get the old menu style?

### Edit

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 
    'container' => '', 
    'menu_class' => 'menu'  
) );
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling the correct menu, and a menu was actually set up for that `theme_location`.

Comment: wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
            'container' => '',
            'menu_class' => 'menu'
        ));

Comment: this way i called the menu

Comment: Is a menu assigned to that location?

Comment: actually are 2 menus assigned in that location.Is that a problem?

Comment: No, that’s not a problem. It is impossible.

Comment: How did you manage to assign two menus to the same Theme Location?

Comment: I've added the same code as my answer in the header and footer of each page and works fine... I don't know what to say...

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer i've added changed the wp_nav_menu args to this:

```
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => '',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
    ));
```

Comment: This is wrong, you should use a proper `theme_location`.

Comment: no it doesnt work if i add a theme location :/

Comment: What, specifically, doesn't work if you add `theme_location`? What is the rendered output? What is the expected behavior? What is not happening as expected, or happening unexpectedly?

Comment: Here is where i found the answer: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-and-wp_page_menu-generate-completely-different-markup?replies=12#post-2414654  i had the same problems